# Appending data to an array

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age, opencypher

I created a vertex with a property called `interests` and it should store an array of strings.

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('DatingApp', $$
    CREATE (v:Person {
        name: 'Alex',
        age: 27,
        occupation: 'Graphic Designer',
        interests: []
    })
    RETURN v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

How can I add more strings to this property with another query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('DatingApp', $$
    MATCH (v:Person { name: 'Alex' }) 
    SET v.interests = v.interests + ['soccer', 'car racing']
    $$) as (v agtype);
```

Please note that this operation does not check whether the data being appended already exists in the array.